# Special chars in the java String

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, byte

I am looking for solution for insert special 1 byte chars in the java String like `0xFE, 0xFF ( > 127)`.

I need use String instead byte array because method of class need String type only.

What I need in the `String = {0x07 0xAA 0x03 FF}`. Yes it is special chars which uses for device control.

And I tried to use String constructur as:

```
byte[] arr = {0x07, (byte) 0xAA, 0x03, (byte) FF};
String s = new String(arr, "UTF-8");
```

//utf-8 uses for 1byte chars, and also I tried ascII, but result was the same

All works up to value 127(dec) of char in array, but after it give strange result like 1 or 2 additional bytes in the String, ofcourse it occured because byte type has max value 127. But how fix this situation?? Need help.

How I understood I can't to add char[] to the String constructor

Comment: "How I understood I can't to add char[] to the String constructor" What do you mean?

Comment: `String` does seem to have a [constructor that takes a `char` array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Use Unicode escapes: `String s = "\u0007\u00AA\u0003\u00FF";`

Comment: Yes I meant that how I know char type take 2 bytes, right? So, char 0xFF will be add to string like 0x00 0xFF, .. but I need 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

One part of your question is incorrect. UTF-8 only stores the printable ASCII characters in the range `[32,126]` as single bytes (beyond that it's 2 or even 3 bytes per character) even though encodings are usually 256 bytes long. Since in Java all Strings are automatically stored and printed as UTF-8 by default, they will remain more than 1 byte when printing.

What you need is an encoding that stores all `[1,256]` first bytes as single bytes when accessing the bytes. For example, with your current code:

```
byte[] arr = {0x07, (byte) 0xAA, 0x03, (byte) 0xFF};
String s = new String(arr, "UTF-8");

System.out.println(s.getBytes().length); // This prints 8
System.out.println(s.getBytes("UTF-8").length); // This prints 8 as well (since the default is UTF-8)
System.out.println(s.getBytes("Windows-1252").length); // This prints 4
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##nZBPb4JAEMXv/RQTTpAoIrSxiemBJnLrSU0PbQ8LbGUt7BJm8E@Mn50uqyaQaGN6md3Zmfd@m7dmGzZcpz9Nk@QMEd6YkIcHgLKOc5EAEiN9bJRIodAje06VkKuPL2AOUFapLcJaW7hCuUuJdVmqing6k4lK9d5sl/CShJLQegLEe@JaG4dVBS9w8HbeZAB2@@qAtwvDga5e0HmKouPUKE9cwLHWSb4993brNABruYiGz5ZzWiWOZOP43JmSZKzS3KTH7QKvkPw@qdX2AL7ueoJAC6zP2vO8SVvD0NyDtkaR1ZUGxujYyrsBm@HF7T/xzvdIvHBVTW6pXSiXNrorTq86TbQdN@dyRZkzhdEIFplAMFsIhaq4xjEJj3f4XNK@aUcZB2QFB4bAYrXhYKOQCTeDlH@zOifQ68bHuYf4LmSqsxiO/Sf/D/DN35/zPjbNLw)

[ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (also known as [Code Page 1252 or Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) or [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) are two pretty well-known encodings.

Comment: Ok, I have found solution, with your help! The problem is charSet !!! need ISO-8859-1

Comment: char[] arr = {0x07, 0xAA, 0x03, 0xFF};
spt.writeString(new String(arr), "ISO-8859-1"); result from portMonitor IRP_MJ_WRITE Serial0 SUCCESS Length 4: 07 AA 03 FF

Comment: @Kost Glad I could help. :)